# Meta Ads campaign not reporting app installs

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest, ads, facebook-ads

I recently created a campaing in Meta Ads to promote my Android app. After a week, the campaing is working fine, impressions are running, money is also and I'm noticing results in the daily installs of my app. However, no installs are being reported in the ads manager, as you can see in the image.

[image]

As some suggest in other posts, I created my app in Meta for developers and, when I created the campaign, I chose the app from the dropdown, not entering the Google Play link.

[image]

And the App Store is configured:

[image]

However, if I click the app in Meta for Developers, in the section "Last Mobile App Installs", it says "We haven't logged any install pings from your app yet.", so it may confirm that no installs are being received from my app.

In my app, I implemented the latest version of the Facebook SDK, which would automatically notify those installs. By adding in the gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
```

I also added to my `strings.xml`

```
<string translatable="false" name="facebook_app_id">xxxxxxxxxx</string>
<string translatable="false" name="facebook_client_token">xxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

And to my manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
```

Lastly but not less weird, in the Events Manager, events for "Activate app" are being received:

[image]

But if I try to configure events with the codeless event setup tool, it says that I have to upgrade my SDK, even if it's supposedly the last version

[image]